# Difference between DBMS and RDBMS with some example tools?

Tags: database, rdbms

What is the difference between a DBMS and an RDBMS with some examples and some new tools as examples. Why can't we really use a DBMS instead of an RDBMS or vice versa?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between DBMS and RDBMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419137/what-is-the-difference-between-dbms-and-rdbms)

Answer (score 1):

A relational DBMS will expose to its users "relations, and nothing else".  Other DBMS's will violate that principle in various ways.  E.g. in IDMS, you could do <ACCEPT <hostvar> FROM CURRENCY> and this would expose the internal record id of the "current record" to the user, violating the "nothing else".

A relational DBMS will allow its users to operate exclusively at the logical level, i.e. work exclusively with *assertions of fact* (which are represented as tuples).  Other DBMS's made/make their users operate more at the "record" level (too "low" on the conceptual-logical-physical scale) or at the "document" level (in a certain sense too "high" on that same scale, since a "document" is often one particular view of a multitude of underlying facts).

A relational DBMS will also offer facilities for *manipulation* of the data, in the form of a language that supports the operations of the relational algebra.  Other DBMS's, seeing as they don't support relations to boot, obviously cannot build their data manipulation facilities on relational algebra, and as a consequence the data manipulation facilities/language is mostly ad-hoc.  On the "too low" end of the spectrum, this forces DBMS users to hand-write operations such as JOIN again and again and again.  On the "too high" end of the spectrum, it causes problems of combinatorial explosion in language complexity/size (the RA has some 4 or 5 primitive operators and that's all it needs - can you imagine 4 or 5 operators that will allow you to do just any "document transform" anyone would ever want to do ?)

(Note very carefully that even SQL systems violate basic relational principles quite seriously, so "relational DBMS" is a thing that arguably doesn't even exist, except then in rather small specialized spaces, see e.g. http://www.thethirdmanifesto.com/ - projects page.)

Comment: Query/manipulate via relational algebra and/or predicate logic, ie conditions.

Answer (score 0):

**DBMS :** Database management system, here we can store some data and collect.
           Imagine a single table , save and read.

**RDBMS :** Relational Database Management , here you can join  several tables together and get related data and queried data ( say data for a particular user or for an particular order,not all users or all orders)

The [Noramalization forms](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) comes into play in RDBMS, we dont need to store repeated data again and again, can store in one table, and use the id in other table,  easier to update, and for reading we can join  both the table and get what we want.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS:
DBMS applications store data as file.In DBMS, data is generally stored in either a hierarchical form or a navigational form.Normalization is not present in DBMS.
RDBMS:
RDBMS applications store data in a tabular form.In RDBMS, the tables have an identifier called primary key and the data values are stored in the form of tables.Normalization is present in RDBMS.